# menu item to point to custom posts list

Tags: custom-post-types

I have created custom post type. It appears in wordpress admin panel and I can add new custom posts (Post type name = "Videos").

I need to have menu item that will link to all posts from given custom post type ('Videos').

1) How to add this menu item? What link to use?
2) Should I create some custom php file to show all posts of custom type or this can be handled by wordpress somehow?

P.S. I have set permalinks to be localhost/myproj/sample-post (currently I am working on localhost).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom menu item link to the menu on `Appearance` => `Menus` => `Edit Menus` => `Links`. Specify the `URL` which shows all videos and `Link text` and click `Add to Menu`. Once added, save the menu and you should see a new menu item on the site end pointing to the videos list.

Comment: I understand what you wrote, however, I am very new to WP. Can you give me a hint, where shoudl I place a file if I wish that those posts are displayed under www.mypage.com/videos?

Comment: There are no files needed. If you have the custom post type correctly and [permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) enabled, then above link should show the videos.

Comment: Doesn't work. I have permalinks configured. localhost/myproj/videos/test-2/ shows one custom post with given title. But localhost/myproj/videos - shows 404 error. I am using thirteen template. The only modification was adding custom post type and changing permalink to http://localhost/myproj/sample-post/